# Jaxb marshaling primitive types

Tags: java, jaxb, double, marshalling, primitive

I have a class with primitive types double and long. While marshaling i have to avoid the variables containing zero value. Tried `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` and inside the same tried to return null values- but failed.

Is there a way?
Searched other threads and cant find a solution

Answer (score 2):

Worked with below adapter

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DoubleAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Double> {

public Object marshal(Double value) {
    if(value == Double.MIN_VALUE){
        return null;
    }
    return value;
}

public Double unmarshal(Object value) {
    return (Double)value;

}
}
```

And it can be used this way in a model class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyModelClass {
   
   @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=double.class, value = DoubleAdapter.class)  
   double someField;
}
```

Comment: add below for attribute  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=double.class,value = DoubleAdapter.class)